# How do I concatenate the folder and the file name with a forward slash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-concatenation

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

folderpath = input("What is the absolute path to Superman's folder?")

mypath = Path(folderpath)

mypath = os.listdir(folderpath)
for files in mypath:
    print ("Found one of Superman's's files..." + files)
#up to here, the code is good

for read in byfiles:
    byfiles = ('mypath\\files')
    byfiles.read_text()
    if "Superman" in read:
        print("Found Superman in file " + read)
```

I need to search the files in input path and locate the word Superman and then print the location where the word was found.  I cannot get the concatenation to work along with the .read_text().

This is the output:

```
What is the absolute path to Superman's folder?C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Superman_files
Found one of Superman's files...boring_document.txt
Found one of Superman's files...eggs.txt
Found one of Superman's files...hello.txt
Found one of Superman's files...secret_document.txt
Found one of Superman's files...spam.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a list of strings so you can check like:

```
for read in mypath:
    if "Superman" in read:
        print("Found Superman in file " + read)
```

if you want to check the content of your file you can use:

```
from pathlib import Path


folderpath = input("What is the absolute path to Superman's folder?")
mypath = Path(folderpath)

for child in mypath.iterdir():
    if child.is_file():
        with open(child, 'r') as file:
            if "Superman" in file.read():
                print("Found Superman in file ",  child.relative_to(mypath))
```

Comment: I tried that and nothing displayed.  How do I make it go through all the files in the folder through concatenation?

Comment: no errors.  The only thing that is displayed is the files names from the previous print "print ("Found one of Superman's's files..." + files)"

Comment: that print it is not helpful it just say that your list `mypath` it is not empty

Comment: there is about 7 .txt files.  Each file contains data and only one of then has the key word.

Comment: Show the output please, and include in the question

Comment: I included the output in the question.

Comment: Check your path, it may not include anything with Superman inside

Comment: I know for sure the word exists in one of those files.

Comment: Inside of file or in the file name?

Comment: inside the file.  not as a file name.

Comment: @AnsBekk check my answer

Comment: here is what I get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iterdir'.  The list object is reffered to mypath!  This is very confusing.

Comment: This works but 2 things:  I don't seem to be able to print the names of the files located in the location (not sure why your code and my code don't work together) and also your code displays the full path to the files, how can I make it display only the file name?

Comment: so you want to display all file names?

Comment: Ok I was able to fix the display of all file names along with your code.  This is solved.  But how can I only display the file name which the word Superman was found versus printing the absolute path?

Comment: so you want to display relative path for the files that has inside Superman ?

Comment: I have updated my answer using `.relative_to` method

Answer (score 0):

```
folder = Path(folder_path)

myfiles = os.listdir(folder)

for file in myfiles:
   file_path = Path.join(folder, file)
   print(file_path) # Here you can perform file_path.read_text()
```

Hope this helps. The code is self explanatory. So I am skipping the explanation.

Comment: This won't work because it does not read the files and search for the key word.  Any clue how I can use filename.read_text() ?